# Google Analytics counts Pageviews in User-ID view weirdly

Tags: google-analytics

I have four views:

- All Visitors
- Logged In Visitors [User-ID enabled]
- Logged In Visitors [by filter]
- Anonymous Visitors

**All Visitors** counts everybody;

**Logged In Visitors [User-ID enabled]** shows only identified clients by using Analytics' internal User-ID Report feature;

**Logged In Visitors [by filter]** also shows only identified clients, but by using a filter: Site User ID [custom] IS NOT EMPTY;

**Anonymous Visitors** on the contrary counts clients with empty Site User ID's.

I set **&uid** and **Site User ID** custom variable only along with each other if I know a site visitor is logged in. So in theory pageviews (not sessions!) of **Logged In Visitors [User-ID enabled]** should be equal to **Logged In Visitors [by filter]** and combined with **Anonymous Visitors** they should add up to All Visitors.

Yet for some reason **Logged In Visitors [by filter]** has ~20% more pageviews than **Logged In Visitors [User-ID enabled]**. Why could that be?

All hits are from a website, no mobile application integration or anything like that. And, again, bear in mind that I'm talking about Pageviews which have as simple logic as it gets -- one refresh is one hit.

I send User ID and the custom dimension like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
if (myClientId) {
    ga('set', '&uid', myClientId);
    ga('set', 'dimension1', myClientId);
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does your "is not empty" filter look like ?

Comment: Include Site User ID regexp ".+"

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be a bug in how the tracking code is being added to the page. Especially since it sounds like there's some extra code to handle population of the myClientId variable.

Have you checked the browser network log on different pages on your site to ensure that each one (or at least the main pages) is definitely only hitting http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif once?

If you're using any technology like rails turbo links, I'd make sure you only get one utm call per page loaded that way as well.

Comment: But even if there were multiple hits per page, how would it explain the difference between the views? There's only one ga('send', 'pageview') that provides stats for both views.

Comment: Pretty sure if there are multiple calls to the tracking gif it will count as multiple page views. What I'm curious about is if there's actually second call to `ga('send', 'pageview')` somewhere. Browser network tab would show that. If it's definitely only one call happening then the answer is probably something else.

Comment: But again, even if there were multiple pageviews per page, they would be counted in both Logged In Visitors [by filter] and Logged In Visitors [User-ID enabled], wouldn't they?